# SSRS Bar Chart Grouping by Date Range

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a dataset that calculates the actual business days.  I've added a bar chart with @beginningdate and @enddate parameters.  When I preview the report it only brings back one bar (the first range "1-10 Days") in the report.

The report renders with all 8 bars on the chart I'm only using the @enddate parameter, but the performance on the report is horrible.

Here's my ranges for the chart:

[image]

I'm sorting the grouping with the following expression:

[image]

Notice the As of Date parameter...this takes a long time to render.

[image]

What I need is to get the bar chart (as shown above) shown the same when I have set-up the grouping when I enter a date range.

As you can see below, the report only returns one bar in the chart even though I have 2 date parameters and changed my dataset `AND A.EFFECTIVEDATE BETWEEN (@ASOFDATE) AND (@ENDDATE)`

[image]

How do I make this work to pull back the bars in the chart when adding a date range?
Hopefully this makes sense.
Thank you,

Comment: are you sure you have anything age 11-30 in the second one? the first one use end data 26th of feb and the second 29th, maybe all the 11-30 are from the 27th to the 30th of jan and get out of range when you move the start date to 31st of jan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this issue out.  What you have to do is right click on the X axis.  Under the Axis Options go to intervals and change it from Auto to 1.  This fixed my issue and I can now run a chart with a date range.

[image]

[image]

My chart looks like this with a date range.

[image]